# Coinbase Pro API GET request returning 400 for /fils and /orders when supplying query parameters

Tags: coinbase-api

I am attempting to make a GET request for the /fills and /orders endpoints and it works if I do not add query parameters, however, if I add the query parameter "product_id=ETH-USD," I then receive a 400 response with an empty message. Is there anything else I need to do to the Authorization Header when making a GET request with query parameters?

Works: https://api.pro.coinbase.com/fills

400 Response: https://api.pro.coinbase.com/fills?product_id=ETH-USD

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question is yes, the Authorization header needs the Body section even for the GET request. The Body section, in this instance, should have ?product_id=ETH-USD in the header signature.